# Toolstrip Container missing from Winforms Designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, .net-5, toolstrip

I'm porting a huge winforms application from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5.
It seems the Toolstrip Container is missing from the Designer. Everything behaves normally in run time, but the designer breaks if the form has a Toolstrip Container in it. Everything gets filled with red crosses, and sometimes VS crashes.
The component toolbar doesn't show Toolstrip Container anymore, but it isn't part of any list of discontinued components and it's still there when I run the program. I searched the web for answers but found nothing.
Has anyone had this experience or knows of any fix for the problem?

Comment: The .NET Core WinForms designer is still a preview, https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/winforms-designer.md

Comment: Test in Microsoft `VS Community 2019 version 16.8.3`, and the `ToolStripContainer` works fine. Try to update your IDE to 16.8.3 or latest version.

Comment: @KyleWang I'm on Enterprise 16.8.6 :(